# Jpgraph: require_once

Tags: php, charts

I'm working on a php project which consist of calculating turboreactors cycles. 
the entry data sent from a form is processed and as outputs i obtain pressures. so i wanna draw a chart of pressure in the same page of the results. 
I wrote this code using jpgraph :

```
erequire_once('../graphe/jpgraph.php');
require_once('../graphe/jpgraph_line.php');

$datay1 = array($Pi0,$Pi0,$Pi2,$Pi4,$Pi5,$Pi7m,$Pi8,$Pi9,$Pi10);

// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(700,400);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();

$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

 $graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','C','D','E','F','G','H'));
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

// Create the first line
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
$p1->SetLegend('Line 1');


$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(1);

// Output line
$graph->Stroke();  
?>
```

the graphe folder which contains jpgrap folder is named graphe
when i send the data i get the pressure but i don't get the chart i get this error msg

> Warning: require_once(../graphe/jpgraph.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\turbo1App\results_mcmfPC.php on line 588

Comment: Can you show us somehow what folders you have and what files they contain?

Comment: @Charis Moutafidis  i put it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: project arborescence]

this what my project folder contains. i hope it would help.

Comment: @Charis Moutafidis dcdfAvcePc.php

Comment: check my answer, I hope this is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: require_once(../graphe/jpgraph.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\turbo1App\results_mcmfPC.php on line 588

This is because you need to write:

```
require_once('./graphe/jpgraph_line.php');
```

or

```
require_once('graphe/jpgraph_line.php');
```

Instead of:

```
require_once('../graphe/jpgraph_line.php');
```

Comment: Moustafidis check my answer

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to set write permission on the image folder

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55807760/edit) some explanation to your answer